# How to regenerate slugs for categories and tag converting non-Latin characters?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, slug

I imported my Blogger to Wordpress, but all the categories and tags urls are missing letters when there is an accented character.

For example, the tag with the name Beyoncé is mysite.com/tags/beyonc

The slugs of the posts imported just fine, and new posts is also working fine replacing é > e, á > a etc..

From all the plugins I searched, none of them converts categories and tags, only post slugs. How can I regenerate all of them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Categories/Tags
2. Edit the Categories/Tags needed (you can quick edit the single ones to make it faster)
3. Clear the Slug field (make it empty, not even a space)

Wordpress will then regenerate the slugs by itself.

Comment: The problem is that I have more then 3.000 tags.. So It would be almost impossible to achieve manually..

Comment: If you need to do it in bulk, then you can always try and delete them from the database via SQL.